# How to handle textOverflow inside a nested column in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have few `Columns` which have rows inside each one, and inside some of those `Rows` i have another nested `Column` that have some text lines, I need to use `TextOverFlow` but every time it fails , ,
here is my code :

```dart
                              Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment:
                                MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Column(
                                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        '${S
                                            .of(context)
                                            .from} : ${chosenStations[0]
                                            .stationName}',
                                        style:
                                        Theme
                                            .of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .body1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        '${S
                                            .of(context)
                                            .to} : ${chosenStations[1]
                                            .stationName}',
                                        style:
                                        Theme
                                            .of(context)
                                            .textTheme
                                            .body1,
                                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
```

And here is the output :

[image]

Comment: you can use wrap widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a Row with single child you can remove it or if you needed you can wrap your container in Expanded widget in Row.